# perl replace string in multiple files

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to replace a string in multiple files. But only the first file gets replaced. The code is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^<section_begin>.*\s+$)/\1<expand>\n/ if $.==1' *exp`

grep -iw "expand" *exp
a3exp:<expand>
```

If I use the same command for an individual file, it's working:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^<section_begin>.*\s+$)/\1<expand>\n/ if $.==1' n2exp
grep -iw "expand" *exp
a3exp:<expand>
n2exp:<expand>
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

According to [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> $. is reset when the filehandle is closed, but **not** when an open filehandle is reopened without an intervening close().
>
> Because "<>" never does an explicit close, **line numbers increase across ARGV files** (but see examples in eof).

*(second emphasis added)*

When you use `-p`, `@ARGV` is set to the list of files you passed on the command line. Since `$.` is not reset when you go to the next file, it will only equal 1 for the first file. You can see this by simply printing `$.`:

```
$ echo foo > foo
$ echo bar > bar
$ perl -pe 'print "$. "' *
1 bar
2 foo
```

(with `-p` lines are printed automatically, so in the above example, the content of each line is printed next to the value of `$.`)

If you `close` the special filehandle `ARGV` when you move to the next file as [mpapec suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407979/176646), `$.` will behave as you expect:

```
$ perl -pe 'print "$. "; close ARGV if eof' *
1 bar
1 foo
```

See the [documentation for eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) for more details and a couple of good examples.

Answer (score 3):

By closing `ARGV` filehandle, line counter `$.` gets reset.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#ARGV

> The special filehandle that iterates over command-line filenames in @ARGV

So you need to explicitly close file when `eof()` is reached,

```
perl -pi -e'
  s/(^<section_begin>.*\s+$)/\1<expand>\n/ if $.==1;
  close ARGV if eof;
' *exp
```

Answer (score 2):

The Unix shell has a lot of tools to workaround this problem. There's `find` with `-exec`:

```
find . -name \*exp -exec perl -pi -e '... if $.==1' {} \;
```

or an old-fashioned `for` loop. In `bash` that would look like

```
for file in *exp
do
    perl -pi -e '... if $.==1' file
done
```

Comment: Sorry, was misusing `xargs`

Comment: Your `find -exec` approach will invoke the Perl interpreter once for each file. It would be better to pipe the results of `find` to Perl, something like: `find -print0 | perl -p0i -e ...` (assuming your version of `find` has `-print0`)

Comment: But of course that approach doesn't fix the OP's problem, so never mind :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eof` or `eof(ARG)` to detect the end of each file and reset `$.` accordinly.

**From the Documentation**

> In a while (<>) loop, eof or eof(ARGV) can be used to detect the end of each file, whereas eof() will detect the end of the very last file only. Examples:

```
# reset line numbering on each input file
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*#/;  # skip comments
    print "$.\t$_";
} continue {
    close ARGV if eof;  # Not eof()!
}
```

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your if $.==1 is getting you. That's lines processed: you're telling it to just process the first line of the input.